# создать json файл на js и с ним работать

Tags: javascript, json, url

Вопрос такой: с помощью только `js` нужно создать файл `json`, записать туда инфу, брать ее от туда, также при изменении в основном файле сохранять изменения. Не знаю, с какой стороны вообще подойти к вопросу. Это нужно реализовать не через `localStorage`. Насколько я поняла, нужно создать файл `json`, создать к нему ссылку и по ней работать. Только как это сделать на `js`?

Comment: на js нельзя создавать файлы

Comment: только если речь идет о `nodejs`

Answer (score 1):

В нативном js чтение из файла можно реализовать приблизительно так

```
function getFileContent (fileName) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', fileName);
    request.onloadend = function() {
        console.log(request.responseText);
    }
    request.send();
}

getFileContent('data.json');
```

Создание файла и запись - разве что на node.js.